# Get multiselect listbox items to print from MS Word userform

Tags: vba, listbox, ms-word, multi-select, userform

I'm trying to get it so that if somebody selects more than one item in a listbox in a userform, those items will all print on a Word document starting at a set bookmark.  I did them as successive If statements hoping that would make it so they just stack on top of each other.  Not working, though.  Any help would be appreciated.  There are more states with contact information, but I thought this would make it easier to work with.

```
With ActiveDocument
  .Bookmarks("Contact").Select
  Dim varItem As Variant
  Dim i As Long
  Do While Len(Me.lstState & vbNullString) > 0
    For Each varItem In lstState
      For i = 0 To Len(Me.lstState) - 1
        If lboState.Selected(i) = "Alabama" Then
          .Selection.WriteLine ("Alabama UI: 866-555-5382")
          .Selection.WriteLine ("www.alabama.com")
          .Selection.WriteLine ("")
        End If
        If lstState.Selected(i) = "Alaska" Then
          .Selection.WriteLine ("Alaska UI: 907-555-5552")
          .Selection.WriteLine ("www.alaska.us")
          .Selection.WriteLine ("")
        End If
      Next i
    Next varItem
  Loop
End With
```

Comment: Next time please describe the specific problems: if there is an error, what is the error and which line raises it. If there is no error, give a detailed explanation of how the observed results differ from the desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you should be looking for:

```
Dim i As Integer

With ActiveDocument
  .Bookmarks("Contact").Select

    For i = 0 To lstState.ListCount - 1
      If lstState.Selected(i) = True Then
        If lstState.List(i) = "Alabama" Then
          Selection.TypeText ("Alabama UI: 866-555-5382") & vbCr
          Selection.TypeText ("www.alabama.com") & vbCr
          Selection.TypeText vbCr
        End If
        If lstState.List(i) = "Alaska" Then
          Selection.TypeText ("Alaska UI: 907-555-5552") & vbCr
          Selection.TypeText ("www.alaska.us") & vbCr
          Selection.TypeText vbCr
        End If
      End If
    Next i
End With
```

Couple things were wrong:

1. You were trying to loop through the selected items incorrectly; you need to increment through each item using lstState.ListCount, which returns a total number of items in the listbox.
2. You were chekcing for the selected value incorrectly; lstState.List(i) will give you the item (the selected state).
3. lboState doesn't exist - probably just a typo from development.
4. Selection is an application-wide property (there is only one at a given time); so .Selection which implies it belongs to ActiveDocument is incorrect.
5. There is not Selection.WriteLine method; use TypeText.

So just a bit of VBA incorrectness, but you'll learn.  I've added a line break after each item (vbCr) but you can play with the formatting more.  Look into SELECT...CASE as well if you plan to go through every state.

**EDIT:** Dimmed i as integer again, as I had ripped out some of OP's code out and forgot to replace it.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much @VBlades!  It worked like a charm.  And I'm sorry for my slow response - I was on vacation all last week.  I'm new to VBA and have never posted to the site, but I am very happy that I did.  Thanks, again!

Comment: @user3781002: Haha, no worries, hope you enjoyed your vaca.  Glad it worked for you.  If you have the chance, please mark this as the answer so that next time somebody has the same question and stumbles upon it, they know it worked. Take care.